# How do I iterate through a HashMap<String, Set<String>> and return which Set<String> is the largest?

Tags: java

I am trying to figure out how to return the largest Set in the Hashmap. I know the basic way of doing it but I cant get it right.

I tried iterating over all the keys in the hashmap by doing the following code. I also just realized that by doing this code, I will only be able to return the size of the largest set not the actual set itself. Is there a much better way? I will greatly appreciate any help! Thank you!

```
Map<String, Set<String>> category = new Hashmap<String, Set<String>>();
int largest = //someInt;
for(String d : category.keySet()) {
    if (category.get(d).size() > //largest)
        largest = category.get(d).size();
} return largest;
```

Comment: what do you mean by largest set? set with largest set size?

Comment: yes that is what I meant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
Map<String, Set<String>> category = new Hashmap<String, Set<String>>();
int largest = 0;
Set<String> largeSet = new HashSet<String>();
for(String d : category.keySet()) {
    if (category.get(d).size() > largest)
        largest = category.get(d).size();
        largeSet = category.get(d);
}
return largeSet;
```

Answer (score 4):

While other answers have shown how you can fix your code, here is another way to do it in a single statement:

```
Set<String> largestSet = category.values().stream()
        .max(Comparator.comparingLong(Set::size))
        .orElse(null);
```

Comment: If you don't particularly care whether the HashMap has entries, `orElse(Collections.emptySet())` might be a bit better. It saves you on null checks, and in a lot of cases might still give the results you want. For instance, if you're just going to iterate through that set, `emptySet()` will do the same as an if-not-null check, and simpler.

Comment: @yshavit I agree. However in this case, I think it would be hard to distinguish whether the Map contained a set with no entries, or the Map itself was empty. But in general I would do what you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You can just do so:

```
Map<String, Set<String>> category = new HashMap<>();
Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();
int largest = 0;
for(String d : category.keySet()) {
    if (category.get(d).size() > largest) {
        largest = category.get(d).size();
        set = category.get(d);
    }
}
return set;
```